# Python/Requets/Beautiful Soup Basic Scrape

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

Hope you're all well. I wrote a basic webscrape of an HTML site earlier today, along similar lines. I was following a tutorial, as you'll be able to see by my code I'm a bit of a green-horn to coding in Python. Hoping for a bit of guidance regarding scraping this site.

As you can see by the commented out code,

```
#print(results.prettify())
```

I am able to successfully able to print out the entire contents of the webpage. What I'd like to do however, is whittle down the contents of what I am printing out, so that I am just printing out the relevant content. There is a lot of content on the page that I don't want, and I'd like massage it out. Does anyone have any thoughts on why the for loop at the bottom of the code is *not* sequentially grabbing up the paragraphs in the xlmins unit of HTML and printing it out? Please see the below code for more.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/7142/7142-h/7142-h.htm"
page = requests.get(URL)

#we're going to create an object in Beautiful soup that will scrape it.
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#this line of code takes

results = soup.find(xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
#print(results.prettify())
job_elems = results.find_all('p', xlmins="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")

for job in job_elems:
    paragraph = job.find("p", xlmins='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
    print(paragraph.text.strip)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `<p>` tag contains the attribute `xlmins='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'`, only the top HTML tag does. Remove that part and you'll get all the paragraphs.

```
job_elems = results.find_all('p')

for job in job_elems:
    print(job.text.strip())
```